# Dynamically typecast the values in to primitive type in apex

Tags: apex

Is there a better approach to do the below functionality dynamically? Based on the data type of the field, I want to typecast the value.

```
if(fieldDataType == 'Boolean'){
   Boolean b = (Boolean) value;
}
if(fieldDataType == 'Currency'){
   Decimal b = (Decimal) value;
}
if(fieldDataType == 'String'){
   String b = (String) value;
}
```

Instead of specifying the above code repeatedly for every datatype, can we do the same in any other optimised way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Apex is a statically typed language, we must have *some* data type that is known at compile time.

If you're working with SObjects, you could use `(SObject)`, if you're working with a custom Apex class that extends another class or implements an interface, you can cast as the parent class/interface.

For primitive types though, an if/else if chain is pretty much the only option we have.